# FastCV Contour Drawing

Tags: computer-vision

I have implemented code for finding and drawing maximum contour using fastcv. But i am not getting the actual output. Finding maximum contour is good. but Drawing that maximum contour is not giving the result. please any suggestion.

```
    unsigned int maxNumContours = 1000;
    unsigned int size  = 0;
    unsigned int sizeOfPointBuffer = 0;
    unsigned int maxPoints= ((2*ImgWidth) + (2 * ImgHeight));

    //Actual Found Contour
    unsigned int pNumContours = 0;

    //Total Number of Points in Each Contour
    unsigned int pNumContourPoints[1000] = {0};

    //Pointer to Start of All Contour
    unsigned int *pContourStartPointsfind[1000];

    size = (maxPoints * sizeof(unsigned int));

    sizeOfPointBuffer = (1000 * 2 * maxPoints * sizeof(unsigned int));
    unsigned int *pPointBuffer=(unsigned int *)malloc(sizeOfPointBuffer);
    memset(pPointBuffer,0,sizeOfPointBuffer);

    int32_t hierarchy[1000][4];

    fcvFindContoursExternalu8(mGr.data,ImgWidth,ImgHeight,ImgWidth,maxNumContours,&pNumContours,pNumContourPoints,pContourStartPointsfind,pPointBuffer,sizeOfPointBuffer,hierarchy,fcvFindContoursAllocate(ImgWidth));

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "JNI PART", "pNumContours = %d \n",pNumContours);

    /*for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "JNI PART", "Number of Points in [%d] = %u \n",j, pNumContourPoints[j]);
    }*/

    int maxContour = pNumContourPoints[0];

    int maxIndex = 0;

    for(int j = 1; j < pNumContours; j++){
        if(pNumContourPoints[j] > maxContour){
            maxContour = pNumContourPoints[j];
            maxIndex = j;
        }
    }

    /*unsigned int *pContourStartPointsdraw[1000];
    for(int i = 0; i < pNumContours; i++){
        pContourStartPointsdraw[i] = pContourStartPointsfind[i];
    }*/



    unsigned int holeflag1[1] = {0};

    unsigned int maxDraw[1] = {0};
    maxDraw[0] = pNumContourPoints[maxIndex];

    unsigned int *pContourStartPointsdraw[1] = {0};
    pContourStartPointsdraw[0] = pContourStartPointsfind[maxIndex];

    unsigned int pointDrawBufferSize = (pNumContourPoints[maxIndex]);

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "JNI PART", "pNumContourPoints[maxIndex] :: %d\n",pNumContourPoints[maxIndex]);



    unsigned int *dummyPointer = pPointBuffer;

    dummyPointer = pContourStartPointsfind[maxIndex];

    unsigned int *pointBufferForDraw = (unsigned int *)malloc(pointDrawBufferSize);

    memset(pointBufferForDraw, 0, pointDrawBufferSize);

    memcpy(pointBufferForDraw, dummyPointer, pointDrawBufferSize);

    /*for(int k = 0; k < pNumContourPoints[maxIndex]; k++) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "JNI PART", "Value of K:: %d\t",k);
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "JNI PART", "Value at PointBuffer:: %d\n",pointBufferForDraw[k]);
    }*/

    fcvDrawContouru8(mContourImg.data,ImgWidth,ImgHeight,ImgWidth,1,holeflag1,maxDraw,(const unsigned int **)pContourStartPointsdraw,pointDrawBufferSize,pointBufferForDraw,&hierarchy[maxIndex],0,2,125,125);
```